# Saving a Twilio SMS response as a model attribute in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

The goal:

I'm using Twilio to send a Response to a user via SMS. Then I ask that user to rate the response, again via SMS. 
I'd like to save the user's Rating as an attribute of the Response model.

The problem(s):

- I don't know how to do this in a smart way. Right now the best I can think of is to find the latest Response sent to that user (Users can have many responses) and give it the rating. But this has some problems, eg., if the user receives multiple responses and wants to rate an old one.
- I am very green and I don't know how to implement the code. This is what I have in the relevant controller:

  ```
  class TwilioController < ApplicationController

    def process_sms
      @rating = params[:Body]
      #Find the response that this rating should get
      #Assign this rating to that response
      if @rating == "10"
        #thanks for the high rating
      else
        #will try to do better next time
      end
    end
  end
  ```

Thanks in advance and please let me know if I can make this question better — this is my first time posting.

Comment: Are you able to successfully receive an SMS from Twilio on the URL associated with this controller method (process_sms)?  If so, then as long as your "Response" model supports a "rating" attribute, you should be able to use that model normally.  Is your question that you're not sure how to create an attribute of a Rails model?

Comment: Yep the SMS comes through successfully. The problem is 1) I'm not sure how to turn that SMS into an attribute of the correct Response model, and 2) I'm not sure how if there's a clever way to detect which Response the Rating corresponds to, since SMS doesn't have threading/replies/etc.

Comment: 1.) This would be the same as any Rails model - create a migration which adds the string to the model and run the migration.  Then, a new attribute should be "settable" on the model.  2.) You should be able to use the REST API to get a list of SMS messages sent to your app from a given number.  Unless your users can rate multiple responses at once, this should give you a list of replies from a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above:

> 1) I'm not sure how to turn that SMS into an attribute of the correct
>   Response model

This would be the same as any Rails model - create a migration which adds the string to the model and run the migration. Then, a new attribute should be "settable" on the model.

> 2) I'm not sure how if there's a clever way to detect which Response
>   the Rating corresponds to, since SMS doesn't have
>   threading/replies/etc.

You should be able to [use the REST API to get a list of SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) sent to your app from a given number. Unless your users can rate multiple responses at once, this should give you a list of replies from a specific user.